# Create Google Map V3 Polygons from XML data

Tags: google-maps, google-maps-api-3

I am trying to create polygons with Data from a XML file. I have never used polygons before and I have studied the Google Map doc examples to get the base features down but the examples don't even work. I tried to merge it with other things I have learned and used to create markers and poly lines but I am missing something and now not only do the polygons not show but the map doesn't even show. I start with base code to display the map and start from there. Once I started adding the code to build the polygon it causes the map to not load. I know I am missing something but I am not sure what exactly since I have never used polygons before.

You can view an example of the XML file I am using for the data. The cords to create the polygons are in a element called "cap:polygon".

http://www.mesquiteweather.net/xml/warnings.xml

Here is the code I have so far...

```
<script type="text/javascript">

var lineColor = {
"Tornado Warning":                   "#FF0000",
"Severe Thunderstorm Warning":       "#FFFF33",
"Flash Flood Warning":               "#00FF00",
};

var infowindow = new google.maps.InfoWindow();

    // start here
    var thisurl = 'xml/warnings.xml';

      function initialize() {
    var myLatlng = new google.maps.LatLng(32.775833, -96.796667);
    var myOptions = {
      panControl: false,
      zoom: 5,
          mapTypeControl: true,
    mapTypeControlOptions: {
      style: google.maps.MapTypeControlStyle.DROPDOWN_MENU
    },
    zoomControl: true,
    zoomControlOptions: {
      style: google.maps.ZoomControlStyle.SMALL,
      position: google.maps.ControlPosition.RIGHT_TOP
    },
      center: myLatlng,     
      mapTypeId: google.maps.MapTypeId.ROADMAP
    }
    map = new google.maps.Map(document.getElementById("map_canvas"), myOptions);

   function MyLogoControl(controlDiv) {
    controlDiv.style.padding = '5px';
    var logo = document.createElement('IMG');
    logo.src = 'http://www.mesquiteweather.net/images/watermark_MW_GMap.png';
    logo.style.cursor = 'pointer';
    controlDiv.appendChild(logo);

    google.maps.event.addDomListener(logo, 'click', function() {
        window.location = 'http://www.mesquiteweather.net'; 
    });
  }

   var logoControlDiv = document.createElement('DIV');
   var logoControl = MyLogoControl(logoControlDiv);
   logoControlDiv.index = 0; // used for ordering
   map.controls[google.maps.ControlPosition.TOP_LEFT].push(logoControlDiv);

  var eventWarnings;

      downloadUrl(thisurl, function(data) {
          var polygon = data.documentElement.getElementsByTagName("feed");  
          var warningCoords = new google.maps.LatLng(cap:polygon),      
  });

  // Construct the polygon
  eventWarnings = new google.maps.Polygon({
    paths: warningCoords,
    strokeColor: lineColor[cap:event],
    strokeOpacity: 0.8,
    strokeWeight: 2,
    fillColor: lineColor[cap:event],
    fillOpacity: 0.35
  });

  eventWarnings.setMap(map);

}
</script>
```

I am stuck at this point and not sure what I am missing. If anyone can offer some advice or suggestions that would be great!

-Thanks!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This is incorrect (I would expect it to give you a javascript error):

```
var warningCoords = new google.maps.LatLng(cap:polygon)
```

A [google.maps.LatLng](https://developers.google.com/maps/documentation/javascript/reference#LatLng) takes two numbers as an argument.  You need to parse the coordinates out of the XML feed, convert them into google.maps.LatLng objects, push them into an array, then provide that array as the paths property in the google.maps.Polygon constructor.

Comment: I would think it would be getting those numbers from the XML element (cap:polygon) to produce the coordinates. Only reason I did it like that is that is how I did it to produce markers. How would I set it up in an array as there will be multiple cords that are always changing since it's being feed via XML? -Thanks!

Comment: I have created two maps identical to the example you provided but the polygons are not showing. I have gone through and looked at the code and compared it for hours and hours and I can't see anything that is wrong. Is there something I am missing that I am over looking http://www.mesquiteweather.net/xml/polywarnings.html and http://www.mesquiteweather.net/googlemap_poly.html

Comment: Try making a copy of the XML, saving that as a file on your server, see if that works.  The headers look pretty much the same to me, you are using Apache, my host is windows.  Don't see anything obvious as to why it isn't working for you.

Comment: Yes the XML is a local XML on my server so it's not fetching it from an outside URL. I have even tried using both relative and absolute file paths

Comment: Running it in a debugger indicates that there are no "entry" tags in the XML, looks like it has already been parsed.  Not sure why that should be different, but you might try removing the `data = xmlParse(data);`

Comment: Success! Removing data = xmlParse(data); did the trick! Thank you so much for the help. I will keep all this in mind for further setups.

Comment: One last question. Is it possible to use an external feed instead of a internal feed or will I need to keep using a cron set for wget to retrieve the XML to store locally on my server?

Comment: There is a cross-domain restriction on XmlHttpRequest.  You can use a proxy on your domain or store a copy locally as you are doing.  The restriction proevents access to URLs not in the same domain as the requesting page.